# OpenX API connection

Tags: asp.net, xml-rpc, openx, openx.net

While trying to connect to OpenX with the following code: (asp.net, c#)

```
IOpenXProxy proxy = (IOpenXProxy)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IOpenXProxy));
proxy.Url = "http://testserver.com/OpenX/www/api/v2/xmlrpc/";
proxy.Logon("username", "password");
```

I am getting an error message:

> Response from server does not contain valid XML. "'--' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '>'. Line 31, position 3."

Using Fiddler it's possible to find out that the response I am getting is http://testserver.com/www/admin/index.php i.e. html login page. Because of that I am getting this error message.
The question is what is wrong? Server settings?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The link was wrong: should be "http://testserver.com/www/api/v2/xmlrpc/".

Answer (score 1):

See [OpenX.NET](https://github.com/mausch/OpenX.Net) to use OpenX from a .Net application. I recommend using ISession instead of IOpenXProxy